# (Python, Scrapy) Taking data from txt file into Scrapy spider

Tags: python, csv, parsing, scrapy

I am new at Python and Scrapy. I have a project. In the spider there is a code like that:

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "project"
    allowed_domains = ["domain.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://domain.com/%d" % i for i in range(12308128,12308148)]
```

I want to take the range numbers between `12308128` and `12308148` from a txt file (or csv file)

Lets say its numbers.txt including two lines in it:

```
12308128
12308148
```

How can I import these numbers to my spider? Another process will change these numbers in txt file periodically and my spider will update the numbers and run.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the start_urls logic in spider's `start_requests()` method:

```
class Myspider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myspider'

    def start_requests(self):
        # read file data
        with open('filename', 'r') as f: 
            start, end = f.read().split('\n', 1)
        # make range and urls with your numbers
        range_ = (int(start.strip()), int(end.strip()))
        start_urls = ["https://domain.com/%d" % i for i in range(range_)]
        for url in start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url)
```

This spider will open up file, read the numbers, create starting urls, iterate through them and schedule a request for each one of them.

Default `start_requests()` method looks something like:

```
def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url)
```

So you can see what we're doing here by overriding it.

Comment: thanks for help but it gives an error while crawl my project. it says `IndentationError: expected an indented block` for this line: `with open('numbers.txt', 'r') as f: `

Comment: ok I think i found problem. It must be connected to `def` line. But it says `SyntaxError: 'yield' outside function ` now

Comment: I think you are misindeted the text when you copied it, make sure the indentation matches to my example. There shouldn't be any errors.

Comment: ok I think i fixed misindeted lines but It didnt work. my spider's output file is 0 byte. btw, your code is for `filename.txt `or  `filename.csv`?

Comment: error is `TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got tuple`

Comment: ok made it. i changed this  `i for i in range(range_)` to this `i for i in range(*range_)`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass any parameters to spider's constructor through command line using option `-a` of `scrapy crawl` command for ex.)

```
scrapy crawl spider -a inputfile=filename.txt
```

then use it like this:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider'
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.infile = kwargs.pop('inputfile', None)

    def start_requests(self):
        if self.infile is None:
            raise CloseSpider('No filename')
        # process file, name in self.infile
```

or you can just pass start and end values in similar way like this:

```
scrapy crawl spider -a start=10000 -a end=20000
```

Comment: thanks for reply but what should i write into range ? how its writes starting and ending number into range with your code?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to read the file and pass the values to your url string

```
Start_Range = datacont.readline()
End_Range = datacont.readline()
print Start_Range
print End_Range
```